# ForeignKey conflict with a column

Tags: api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create an entity `Client` with login, password, role and tasks as properties. The idea of program is a teacher (role == teacher) can create tasks and a student (role == student) can see them. I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API.

So, this is what I have:

client:

```cs
public class Client : BaseEntity
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Todo> Tasks { get; set; }
    public Roles Role { get; set; }
}
```

Todo:

```cs
public class Todo : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid TeacherId { get; set; }
    public List<Client> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And role

```cs
public class Roles
{
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Migration is created, but when I update the database, I get an error:

> The ALTER TABLE conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Students_Role_RoleStudent". The conflict occurred in database "TodoDb", table "dbo.Students", column 'Student'

Also, this is the `dbcontext`:

```cs
public class EfCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Todo> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }

    public EfCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<EfCoreDbContext> options)
        :base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>().HasKey(x => x.Student);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

If something is wrong with entity, please, let me know

Comment: What is BaseEntity in your code ?

Comment: Any reason you're defining Roles with two properties instead of creating a `Role` class which has the information of a Role (e.g. RoleId, RoleName etc.) Then the `Client` has a RoleId which serves as the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

At first it might seem strange that `dbo.Students` has a column `Student`. This is because EF Core automatically created it as a foreign key to `dbo.Roles`.

However, without knowing your previous data and model (before applying the migration) I cannot tell why the foreign key constraint fails.

In case there is no specific reason to have a `class Roles` like you do, I would strongly recommend to change that entity:

#### Hard code roles

This way is easiest to implement but you need to change your code if roles change. The role will be saved as a string column in `dbo.Clients` which I renamed because teachers use the same table.

```cs
public enum Role
{
    Student,
    Teacher
}

public class EfCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Todo> Tasks { get; set; }

    public EfCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<EfCoreDbContext> options)
        :base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .Property(x => x.Role).HasConversion<string>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

#### Use dynamic roles

This approach is more complicated but you can change roles at runtime without changing your code. Before choosing this approach make sure you know how `JOIN` operations work in EF Core and what's the difference between lazy and [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager).

```cs
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EfCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Todo> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public EfCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<EfCoreDbContext> options)
        :base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```